# How to update specific raster tiles which are a part of very big basemap covering multiple countries using gdal2tiles.py or rasterio?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I pre-rendered a custom base map spanning across multiple countries using `gdal2tiles.py` and it works like a charm. But I don't know how to update only specific tiles when there is a data update for lets say 1/3 of the basemap. So I have two questions here

1) How to update specific tiles across multiple zoom levels for a pre rendered base map?

2) Is it possible to dynamically render raster tiles (from satellite images) in the query time?

Any kind of help is appreciated

I have already tried to render only the specific tiles for the updated data but it ended up breaking the shared tiles between two different datasets ( example two landsat tiles).